# How to create a group of Buttons with Checkbox functionality?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, frontend, reactstrap, chakra-ui

```js
import { HStack, VStack, Button, CheckboxGroup, useCheckboxGroup, Input, IconButton, Switch, FormControl,Box, useColorMode } from '@chakra-ui/react';  

<HStack width='100%' justifyContent='space-around' paddingBottom='10'>
          <Button colorScheme ='qTurquoise' variant='ghost'>
               TOP PLOT
          </Button>
          <Button colorScheme = 'qPurple' variant='ghost'>
               TOP ACTING
          </Button>
          <Button colorScheme = 'qPurple' variant='ghost'>
               TOP CINEMATOGRAPHY
          </Button>
          <Button colorScheme = 'qPurple' variant='ghost'>
               TOP NOVELTY
          </Button>
          <Button colorScheme = 'qPurple' variant='ghost'>
               TOP ENDING
          </Button>
</HStack>
```

I am using ChakraUI but I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem using Chakra, I'm open to using other React frameworks or just doing it from scratch in React. But I am not sure how to accomplish it. I found a [Checkbox Button](https://reactstrap.github.io/?path=/docs/components-button--checkbox-and-radio) in the Reactstrap framework, however, I'm not sure I'm going to be able to customize it in the ways that I need to.

I currently have an Hstack of buttons, created using Chakra, [displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqR5u.png)
more or less how I would like them to, but I need them to have the functionality of a checkbox/ checkbox group, where I can select multiple of them at once, turning them on and off like filters for content. I'm open to the inverse situation of making a checkbox component look like a button as well, if there are options available to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an simple example to customise the checkbox group component in Chakra UI

```
function Example() {
  

  function CustomCheckbox(props) {
    const { state, getCheckboxProps, getInputProps, getLabelProps, htmlProps } =
      useCheckbox(props)

    return (
      <chakra.label
        display='flex'
        flexDirection='row'
        alignItems='center'
        gridColumnGap={2}
        maxW='40'
        bg='green.50'
        border='1px solid'
        borderColor='green.500'
        rounded='lg'
        px={3}
        py={1}
        cursor='pointer'
        {...htmlProps}
      >
        <input {...getInputProps()} hidden />
        <Flex
          alignItems='center'
          justifyContent='center'
          border='2px solid'
          borderColor='green.500'
          w={4}
          h={4}
          {...getCheckboxProps()}
        >
          {state.isChecked && <Box w={2} h={2} bg='green.500' />}
        </Flex>
        <Text color="gray.700" {...getLabelProps()}>Click me for {props.value}</Text>
      </chakra.label>
    )
  }

  const { value, getCheckboxProps } = useCheckboxGroup({
    defaultValue: ['2'],
  })

  return (
    <Stack>
      <Text>The selected checkboxes are: {value.sort().join(' and ')}</Text>
      <CustomCheckbox {...getCheckboxProps({ value: '1' })} />
      <CustomCheckbox {...getCheckboxProps({ value: '2' })} />
      <CustomCheckbox {...getCheckboxProps({ value: '3' })} />
    </Stack>
  )
}
```

For more details https://chakra-ui.com/docs/hooks/use-checkbox-group

Comment: only issue with this is it's not keyboard accessible. I can't hit spacebar to 'check"